# Zend Framework: Render multiple Views in one Layout

Tags: zend-framework, zend-view

I want to generate a dynamic site using Zend_Layout.

My layout (/application/layouts/scripts/layout.phtml) contains the following lines:

```
...        
<body>

        <?php echo $this->render('header.phtml') ?>

        <div id="content"><?php echo $this->layout()->content ?></div>

        <?php echo $this->render('footer.phtml') ?>

    </body>
...
```

If i browse to my index controller index action - Zend renders the index view (application/views/scripts/index/index.phtml) inside of $this->layout()->content automatically.

Now i want to render the views of to different controller actions in the layout.
So i generate a new controller auth with an action login that shows a login form.

I change my layout to:

```
  ...        
    <body>

            <?php echo $this->render('header.phtml') ?>

            <div id="content"><?php echo $this->layout()->content ?></div>
            <div id="login"><?php echo $this->layout()->login ?></div>

            <?php echo $this->render('footer.phtml') ?>

        </body>
    ...
```

When i browse to index/index, i want to define in this action that zend should render auth/login view inside $this->layout()->login and for example news/list inside of $this->layout()->content.

index/index is than a kind of a page layout -
and auth/login and news/list a kind of widget

How to do this?

Comment: Actually another question, what do you prefer to use view helpers or view scripts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First advice is to avoid the Action view helper at all costs, it will probably be removed in ZF 2.0 anyway.  ([ZF-5840](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-5840))  ([Why the actionstack is evil](http://www.rmauger.co.uk/2009/03/why-the-zend-framework-actionstack-is-evil/))

This is related to a [question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941216/action-view-helper-in-zend-work-around) - and bittarman's answer is pretty useful.  The best way to implement something like that is to have a view helper that can generate your "login" area.  `My_View_Helper_Login` for instance.  Then your layout can call `$this->login()`, and so can the view script for `user/login`.  As far as having `index/index` render the content from `news/list` just forward the request to the other controller/action from the controller.  `$this->_forward('list', 'news');`

Answer (score 3):

I would also advise against using the `action view helper`. Unless you have a bunch of logic in your controller, you probably don't need to dispatch another request to another controller just to render a view partial.

I would recommend simply using a view partial just like you have done with your `header.phtml` and `footer.phtml`:

```
<body>

        <?php echo $this->render('header.phtml') ?>

        <div id="content"><?php echo $this->layout()->content ?></div>

        <div id="login"><?php echo $this->render('auth/login.phtml') ?></div>

        <?php echo $this->render('footer.phtml') ?>

</body>
```

And maybe your `auth/login.phtml` view script looks like this:

```
<div id="login_box">
    <?php if (empty($this->user)): ?>
        Please log in
    <?php else: ?>
        Hello <?php echo $this->user->name ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

As long as you set your view variables at some point in your controller, you can call the `render view helper` from within a view (or even a controller if you wanted to).

```
#index controller
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->view->user = Model_User::getUserFromSession();
}
```

Comment: What if we're not in index/index (index controller, index action), view->user will not be defined, how to make the logic behind view->user separate from the current action? Seems like the answer as far as I found in my research is a view helper, right..?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the not so speed performant

```
$this->action()
```

or you try it with

```
$this->partial()
```

(see http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.partial )

Comment: I'd advise against `$this->action()` it is very inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I got to this page when looking for an answer to my own problem, which was that my layout got called multiple times. This happened because of multiple reasons:

1) I made a bad ajax call, had  /help instead of /module/help

2) I called an action, exampleAction(), I had to put a

```
$this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
```

To prevent the layout from being rendered again.

3) I did a redirect, try using a forward or route.