# How to call multiple actions of multiple modules from different controller and combine the output?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Suppose I have the following code.

```
class Module1_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
  public function indexAction() {
    $this->view->data1 = "This is module1's index action view";
  }
}

class Module2_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
  public function indexAction() {
    $this->view->data2 = "This is default module2's index action view";
  }
}

class Default_IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
  public function indexAction() {
    // $module1_output = Call Module1_IndexController's indexAction view output
    // $module2_output = Call Module2_IndexController's indexAction view output

    $this->_helper->actionStack("index", "index", "module1");
    $this->_helper->actionStack("index", "index", "module2");
  }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve the output like the one in the last controller ? I am using zend framework 1.11 and are there any other solutions to achieve this functionality ?

In **modules/module1/views/scripts/index/index.phtml**, I have

```
$module1NavArray = array(
        array( 'label' => 'Nav1', 'uri' => '/home/module1/nav1' )
);
$container = new Zend_Navigation($module1NavContainer);
print $this->navigation( $container );
```

And in **modules/module2/views/scripts/index/index.phtml**

```
$module2NavArray = array(
        array( 'label' => 'Nav2', 'uri' => '/home/module2/nav2' )
);
$container = new Zend_Navigation($module2NavContainer);
print $this->navigation( $container );
```

The output of the default module's index action is Nav2 link is printed 2 times. However, if the print a string instead of navigation, then the output is as desired like "Nav2" and "Nav1" sequentially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Action View Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.action) will help you to accomplish this

in **modules/default/views/scripts/index/index.phtml**

```
<?php echo $this->action('index', 'index', 'module1')); ?>

<?php echo $this->action('index', 'index', 'module2'); ?>
```

But action view helper have several performance and debugging issues please see these links before deciding to use it

[How can I speed up calls to the action() view helper?](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/performance.view.html#performance.view.action)
[Action View Helper in Zend - Work around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941216/action-view-helper-in-zend-work-around)
[Using Action Helpers To Implement Re-Usable Widgets](http://mwop.net/blog/246-Using-Action-Helpers-To-Implement-Re-Usable-Widgets.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and with your suggestion and In default module's controller I have added like $this->_helper->actionStack("index", "index", "module1"); and also for module2. This output is excellent. However, if I use Zend_Navigation($arrayData) in modules/module1/views/scripts/index/index.phtml and in modules/module2/views/scripts/index/index.phtml, the last actionStack is repeated. How can I use Zend_Navigation in view file with actionStack ?

Comment: what do u meant by " the last actionStack is repeated" ?

Comment: I have edited the problem and so you could understand the problem more clearly.

Comment: i am not sure about the cause of this issue... may be dispatch flow issue or handling multiple instance

Comment: can you check this ZF bug.. seems like this is the one you have http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-6865

Comment: The issue was solved using $this->navigation()->menu()->render($navigationContainerObject); Thanks Nandakumar.